# Call to a member function all() on string laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, request

Im having a trouble to show the errors on my view.
Im using request, and also i am validating in the controller.

This is the part of the view on the code that has errors.

```
@if ($errors->any())
              <div class="col-md-12">
              <label>Errores</label>
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
              @endif
              </div>
```

I also try to change the **$errors->any** for **$errors->all** and nothing.

This is the part of the controller code that has the other validation, and this is the one that is having trouble with the other view code.

```
public function store(ComplejoStoreRequest $request)
    {     
        $complejos=new Complejos();
        $complejos->nombre_complejo=$request->nombre_complejo;
        $complejos->categoria=$request->tipocomplejo;
        $complejos->id_tipo_sede=$request->sede;

        $cantidadComplejos = Sede::find($request->sede)->complejos->count();

        if($cantidadComplejos==3)
            return redirect()->to('complejos/create')->with('errors','Ya la sede tiene 3 complejos!');

        //$complejos->localizacion_complejo=$request->localizacion_complejo;
        $complejos->jefe_organizacion=$request->jefe;
        $complejos->area=$request->ocupacion;
        $complejos->estado=$request->estado; 

            $complejos->save();
```

and this is the code in my **request**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ComplejoStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre_complejo' => 'required|max:25|unique:complejos,nombre_complejo',
            'jefe' => 'required|max:25|unique:complejos,jefe_organizacion',            
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
{
    return [
        'nombre_complejo.required' => 'Debe ingresar el nombre del complejo',
        'nombre_complejo.unique' => 'El nombre del complejo ya se encuentra registrado',
        'jefe.required' => 'Debe ingresar el nombre del jefe de la organización',
        'jefe.unique' => 'El/la jefe/jefa de la organización ya se encuentra registrado',


    ];



}

}
```

I want to show all the validations messages in the request, and also want to show the validations messages on the controller.

What do i have to do?

Comment: You're passing a single string back via `->with('errors','Ya la sede tiene 3 complejos!');`. Laravel expects `$errors` to be a `MessageBag` instance, generally returned via `->withErrors($vaildator)` (or similar). If this is a custom error message, consider changing the key to something like `->with('error_message`, '...')`

Comment: And where do i config the 'error_message' value? Because if i change the 'errors' to 'error_message', still dont show in the view when validation is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// controller
if($cantidadComplejos==3)
   return redirect()->to('complejos/create')->with('err','Ya la sede tiene 3 complejos!');

//blade

@if(session()->has('err'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{!! session('err') !!}</div>
@endif

@if ($errors->any())
     <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Errores</label>
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Glad to help ! :)